# Can't clear radio buttons

Tags: jquery, button, radio-button

How can I clear these check boxes:

```
<form class="betMatch" id="4">

<table class="grid-info">
 <tr>                
  <td><input type="radio" class="betMatchWin" id="49" value="1" name="betmatch1" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" class="betMatchCover" id="49" value="2" name="betmatch1" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

My JQuery:

```
var x=1;

$('form.matchBet#4 input:radio[name=betmatch'+x+']').attr('checked',false);
```

I can't see why it won't work but the buttons will not clear....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apologies guys, all of your answers were correct, but I had the x variable set incorrectly so although the class and id for the form were correct I was referencing the wrong radio name. Apologies for wasting your time :0(

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.removeAttr('checked')
```

or

```
.prop('checked',false)
```

Second is better - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Ah yes .. there's an error in the code ^_^ Should be:

```
var x=1;

$('form.betMatch#4 :radio[name=betmatch'+x+']').prop('checked',true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fGkM3/

(only the second gets checked because they have the same name and that's how radio buttons work .. that's just an example, use `false` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$('form.matchBet#4 input:radio[name=betmatch'+x+']').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: I just noticed that I have several sets of radio buttons on the page with the same name class and id. however the form id is different so this should make them distinct right?

Comment: Try this $(':radio[name=betmatch'+x+']',$('form.matchBet#4')).removeAttr('checked');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear them all:

```
$('form.betMatch#4 :radio[name=betmatch'+x+']').each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: I think that the $(this) object is interfering with the rest of my script - it screws things up

Comment: `$(this)` is contained within the function. It shouldn't mess with anything...ill make a fiddle to demo it. Give me a few mins.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/JmJAY/ .. Run it, check a radio, click the button, it clears.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

$('input[name=betmatch'+x+']').removeAttr('checked');

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Clear Radio Button</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clear_radio(){
            var x = 1;
            $('input[name=betmatch'+x+']').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="betMatch" id="4">

    <table class="grid-info">
        <tr>         
            <td><input type="radio" class="betMatchWin" id="49" value="1" name="betmatch1" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="betMatchCover" id="49" value="2" name="betmatch1" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript: clear_radio()" value="clear" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it works...